# Chown Operation not permitted:

Tags: python, chown

**The main problem was that I had not restarted my computer yet, after restarting, `os.chown`, `shutil.chown` and other commands worked just fine as long as I moved the permissions to a group that I am also a member of**

I've downloaded a zip file from an api and saved it using:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response, \
        open(out_folder, 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
```

I would like to allow another user acces to this file. However, I've not been able to do so. I've tried:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['chown', '-R', f"{user}:{user}", out_folder],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.communicate()
```

Which fails for every statement telling me that the operation is not permitted.

Next, I tried adding `sudo` to the list of commands, but this only resulted in the `process.communicate()` line hanging forever.

Next, I tried:

```
shutil.chown(out_folder, user=user)
```

Which also did not work. I thought perhaps it would work if I wrote it instead to a shared group that I and the other user are both part of:

```
shutil.chown(out_folder, group=shared_group)
```

This also failed, again with the permission error.

I'm fresh out of ideas and don't know what to do. Is it perhaps possible to immediately write files to the correct user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a working solution:

```
import pwd
import grp
import os


uid = pwd.getpwnam(usernmae).pw_uid    
gid = grp.getgrnam(groupname).gr_gid
os.chown(out_folder, uid, gid)
```

Strangely enough it doesn't work for all groups I'm a member of **(this was solved by restarting my computer)**

Answer (score 0):

The one user who can execute a `chown` at any moment is `root`. I'd advise you to launch your program/script as a `root` user (or using `sudo`).

`chown` can also be used, when the file whose permissions you want to change, is in the same group as you are, or, if both groups are linked (see `/etc/groups`, sorry I don't know the syntax by heart).

Comment: This works, but in the end I want to make this into a docker image to run it automatically. I cannot execute a file as sudo.

Comment: Is it really impossible to chown a file to a group I'm part of without resorting to sudo?

Comment: @Nathan: I've edited my answer according to your comment.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It turned out to be useful, so I've upvoted it, but it didn't answer the question so I won't accept it as not to confuse future readers